# dpkg: error processing (--unpack)

Tags: dpkg

When I try to update the system(s`udo apt-get update`) or install something (`sudo apt-get install` ...) it returns the following error :

```
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/liblove-unstable0_0.10.0~pre2657ppa2_amd64.deb (--unpack)
```

Anyone can help me? 
Thank You , and sorry for my english.

Answer (score 3):

It is telling you that an archive it downloaded (`/var/cache/apt/archives/liblove-unstable0_0.10.0~pre2657ppa2_amd64.deb`) is invalid, and cannot be unpacked. Since the file is in the `/var/cache/...` hierarchy, you can probably delete the file (`sudo rm /var/cache/apt/archives/liblove-unstable0_0.10.0~pre2657ppa2_amd64.deb`), and let the system download a good copy.